# Wi-fi clustering without cables

Tags: vlan, ieee-802.11

From my point of view, all Wireless networks are cabled to something, Router/VLAN or subnet.

Am trying to build a local network system that is distributed wirelessly, For example one Router in Region-A(100 meters distance) can connect to another Router in Region-B(100 meters distance) to form a single network system, in a way that all devices connected to this network can share data.

I know someone might say that the routers need some physical contact/access in order to form that single network system but i've heard that Facebook is doing it! Facebook is distributing it's data connection using planes and i assumes the planes are not wired to anything.

Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks that you do not control are explicitly off-topic here. You are going to need to ask the network owner.

Comment: @RonMaupin now am scared, i guess this is a challenge for your community. You need to adjust your terms as this is a place for obtaining knowledge.

Comment: The community decided on what is on-topic, and what is off-topic. It is spelled out in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @RonMaupin Yeah i read that, but this is a professional question and am not trying to control someone's else network, am trying to set up a professional wireless system, i've made reference to Facebook's structure so that someone with an answer can relate to my context. You are taking this the wrong way sir.

Comment: You can rephrase your question to bring it in line with what is on-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin please check my updated question sir, i think it's not off-topic now

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more information. For instance, what distance between the networks?

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes Sir, i've added the distance between the regions, please share your knowledge on this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this several ways. Probably the easiest is to get a wireless bridge and use directional antennae on both your WAP and wireless bridge.

For such a short distance, It may be better just to extend the network with fiber.

Comment: For example Router-A connects to Router-B, assuming i have a server connected to Router-B, will the clients of Router-A connect to this server.

Comment: If you have a WAP on your main network that connects to a wireless bridge on the other network, and you configure routing between the two networks, then the two networks should be able to share resources. You can configure ACLs to allow or block access to various network resources. This is all very basic. Your company may want to hire a consultant for guidance. Remember that you don't own the airwaves, and performance may be bad and vary. That is why I would use fiber between the two networks.

Comment: Much appreciation Sir, would you kindly share your views on this one http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/36626/30390