# Multiple routers with one long range antenna

Tags: router, vlan, ieee-802.11

Wifi routers have a limit on the number of clients that can connect,

Assuming i have many routers and i connect them  together via wireless bridge, then i connect one single long-range antenna that can spread the network over a mile or so.

Will this allow me to handle more clients?

Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @RonMaupin Can you please share your views on this

Comment: Wi-Fi is bi-directional. You may be able to use directional antennae to do a point-to-point link, but you have to remember that the hosts need to be able to send to the AP, too, and the radios and antennae in hosts are usually pretty limited. Wi-Fi was never designed to blanket a huge area like I think you want. I'm not sure why you are referring to routers. You put in routers where you want to route between networks. To cover a large area, you need a bunch of WAPs using a wireless controller for roaming.

Comment: @RonMaupin So that means, WAPs can connect to a router wirelessly without a physical cable?

Comment: No. The WAPs are your wireless connection points. They connect back to your network, usually a switch, with wires. You WLC will control the WAPs, and allow seamless roaming. Each WAP will handle about 20 to 30 users. This is done by companies all the time.

Comment: You really, really need to go into a lot more detail of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RonMaupin Much appreciation Sir, Now i understand. so the antennas are only there to connect two separate networks via routers? right?
How do i Boost the WAPs signals so that they can reach a user in a one mile distance range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48779/discussion-between-tuna-and-ron-maupin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to cover a large network area with a single Wi Fi connection,But Like Ron Maupin mentioned in the comments above, All i need to do is set up the network in different areas then i connect them using point-to-point antennas via the routers, then split the connections from each router to a bunch of WAPs.